# Overflows on an established saltwater aquarium

Tags: aquarium, reef-tank

So I have a 120 gallon saltwater aquarium with 4 1" bulkheads in back. There is a pair on either side of 4' long aquarium each pair have hold 10" apart. Right now I just have screens over the bulkheads and that is how I'm running my drains down to sump. My question is, can I silicone some 3 walled overflows around each set of bulkheads with fish and livestock in still and just drain maybe 5 inches lower than the drains? I'm pretty sure I have zero surface skimming going on at the present moment and I am developing a film on the top layer of water[image]

Comment: I can't tell from the picture, but do the drains go out the back of the tank?